# How do I add or remove an off-screen row at the top of a Table View without scrolling?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` containing a list of items.

When the user taps the *Edit* `UIBarButtonItem`, the top row needs to be removed, because it is not editable.

I do that like this:

```
- (void) setEditing: (BOOL) editing animated: (BOOL) animated
{   
    if (editing)
    {
        [self.theTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths: [NSArray arrayWithObject: [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: 0 inSection: 0]] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
        // call super afterward so the user doesn't see the row get an editing accessory before it disappears
        [super setEditing: editing animated: animated];
    }
    else
    {
        [super setEditing: editing animated: animated];
        [self.theTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths: [NSArray arrayWithObject: [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: 0 inSection: 0]] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
    }
}
```

This code (unrelated bits snipped) works just fine, with one caveat:

If the user is anywhere but at the top of the table (assuming there is more than a single screenful of row), the animation behavior causes the entire table view to scroll up (or down), and the behavior of the last row in the table is, at best, usable.

**My question:** How can I only make the top row animate out when the user can see it, but when the user can't see it, it just disappears, but does not cause the table to scroll.

Comment: You don't want to use editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn’t appear to be any simple solution to this. I’ve had limited success with completely custom behavior in a `UICollectionView`, but major versions of iOS and years later, even Apple’s own built-in apps continue to get this edge case wrong.

Comment: What about Anna's comment above? This should work even 6 years later.

Comment: @HAS: `editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath` isn’t relevant because I wanted the cell removed, not altered, when editing. `editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath` is for displaying an add or delete control, or not displaying the default delete control. The question is about a bug when removing rows at index paths that are no longer on-screen. `UITableView` likes to adjust the scroll offset when it shouldn’t, causing a visual bug.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `UITableViewRowAnimationBottom` instead of `UITableViewRowAnimationTop`?

Otherwise you can manually set the `contentOffset` property of the `UITableView` to adjust for the missing row.

Answer (score 0):

Try using UITableViewRowAnimationRight.  That should make the cell slide out if it's visible, but otherwise leave your table intact.

Answer (score 0):

Before you do the animation check if the first row is visible.

If yes, peoceed.

Else, you want it not to appear when the user scrolls up, right? so replace the table's data source with one without the first row and after editing ends return the first row to that data source.

Another option might be not displaying it by manipulating 
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
But that is probably a bad practice.